# How to console.log while using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Simple question: I have a React & webpack-based SPA. 
For `index.js`, the following code:

```
console.log (`index.js`)
```

produces a white screen and a console log :D

The following code:

```
console.log (`index.js`)
import App from 'containers/app'
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById (`app`)
)
```

produces a **single** console log:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call bla bla bla
```

Ok I get I have a hook bug, but how can I console-log-debug it if the error consumes the entire console? I even tried setting Chrome's console settings to Preserve logs.

And more importantly, how is that even possible? Even if `App` was some asynchronous function, surely `console.log` should run first??

Thanks!

Comment: `console.clear = () => {}` at the top of index.js doesn't work either. Must I have to go to traditional debugging? :)

Comment: I should have mentioned for completeness that It compiles successfully! My best guess is the code throws *before* execution, does React do some kind of static analysis on the output? It's pretty tricky imo

Comment: I found it! Changing to `require` produces the expected result. I'll investigate and write an answer.

Comment: what are you trying to log using console.log (`index.js`)?

Comment: Well I want my logs to run synchronously so I can investigate the error...

Comment: can you show your hook code, this is not going to help you debugging the error as this

Answer (score 0):

ES6 imports are hoisted. That's what produces the unexpected result. The good news is they are executed in order. So I'm going to do a depth-first-search to find the problem :P

PS: this relies inspecting Babel output, but in so far as babel doesn't have a bug, should hold for true ES6 too.

PS2: I tried 4 different Babel plugins that would convert `imports` to `require's` to make this process a little easier, none of them are maintained or worked (in case this saves somebody precious time

Comment: Somebody asked why don't I just find the error. Well I just refactored all of my HOC's to hooks, so that wouldn't be so nice...

Comment: just found the issue! Hooray